# Is there any method to extract a table from a lengthy PDF using UiPath?

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, pdf-extraction

I need to write a process to extract several tables from a lengthy PDF having 20-25 pages using UiPath. The problem here I faced was the number of pages getting changed monthly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Read PDF Text activity with the Range property set to “All” to read the whole PDF regardless of the number of pages. Then use regex to manipulate the text and extract the data. Hard to give a more detailed answer without seeing the exact format of the PDF and tables you want to extract.